# How to test the upper layers of a ZF application

Tags: unit-testing, zend-framework, testing, integration-testing

How do you test the controller and views in a Zend Framework application?

I have been using PHPUnit to test the mapper, domain and services, and that's been working fine.  I use dependency injection so that I can isolate the class under test.

When it comes to the controller however I would probably not try to isolate it.  I would effectively be doing integration tests at this point, but I think that's fine.  I would still use PHPUnit and fire off requests for most tests.

For the views, I am thinking of using the CSS selectors in Zend_Test, but since I have a lot of Javascript I will have to use selenium too.

Does this all sound reasonable?  What do you do?

Comment: look at behat for BDD, you get more benefits from the time spent in writing tests, including a better understand by the business

Comment: i prefer selenium + selenium rc under phpunit. Works most times like a charme.